# Treeview not displaying data when image option is given in tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, treeview

I am working on an app. I need to display the details from the table staff_details which has the attributes staff_id, name, email, qualification, contact, image.The image is stored as LongBlob. I used treeview to display it.

I am populating the treeview columns based on user input which I get as checkbox values. The selected options are populated in the list `attributes_selected`.

I want to display image in the column 0 of the treeview.

I am able to display the details staff_id, name, email, qualification, contact using the code `self.my_tree.insert(parent="",index='end',iid=count,text='Parent',values=record)` in the for loop but when I try to display image using `image=`  option it display blank treeview. It shows no error.

[image]

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

This is my code

```
class AdminSelectStaff(BasePage):

    def __init__(self,parent,controller):

        super().__init__(parent, controller)
        ...
        admin_frame = tk.Frame(admin_window, width=200, height=150, highlightbackground="black", highlightthickness=1,bg="white")
        admin_frame.grid(row=30, column=0, padx=25, pady=50)

        var1 = IntVar()
        var2 = IntVar()
        var3 = IntVar()
        var4 = IntVar()
        var5 = IntVar()


        self.check_button1 = tk.Checkbutton(admin_frame, text="Staff Id", background='white', variable=var1, onvalue=1,offvalue=0, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.check_button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.check_button2 = tk.Checkbutton(admin_frame, text="Name", background='white', variable=var2, onvalue=1,offvalue=0, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.check_button2.grid(row=10, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.check_button3 = tk.Checkbutton(admin_frame, text="Email", background='white', variable=var3, onvalue=1,offvalue=0, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.check_button3.grid(row=20, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.check_button4 = tk.Checkbutton(admin_frame, text="Qualification", background='white', variable=var4, onvalue=1,offvalue=0, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.check_button4.grid(row=30, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)
        self.check_button5 = tk.Checkbutton(admin_frame, text="Contact", background='white', variable=var5, onvalue=1,offvalue=0, font=("Helvetica", 12))
        self.check_button5.grid(row=40, column=0, sticky='w', padx=10, pady=10)
        ...
        self.select_staff_button = tk.Button(admin_frame, text="Select Staff", width=15, font=("Helvetica", 12), bg="white",command=lambda: select_staff(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5))
        self.select_staff_button.grid(row=70, column=25, padx=10, pady=10)

        def select_staff(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5):
            self.vertical_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(admin_frame)

            self.vertical_scrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

            self.my_tree = ttk.Treeview(admin_frame, yscrollcommand=self.vertical_scrollbar.set)

            self.my_tree.pack()

            self.vertical_scrollbar.config(command=self.my_tree.yview)

            style = ttk.Style(admin_frame)
            style.theme_use("winnative")
            style.configure(".", font=("Helvetica", 11))
            style.configure("Treeview.Heading", font=("Helvetica", 11, "bold"))

            self.my_tree['columns'] = tuple(self.attributes_selected)

            self.my_tree.column("#0", width=20, stretch='NO')

            for x in self.attributes_selected:
                self.my_tree.column(x, width=100, anchor='w')

            self.my_tree.heading("#0", anchor='w', text='Image')


            for x in self.attributes_selected:
                if (x == "staff_id"):
                    self.my_tree.heading("staff_id", anchor='w', text="Id")
                if (x == "name"):
                    self.my_tree.heading("name", anchor='w', text="Name")
                if (x == "email"):
                    self.my_tree.heading("email", anchor='w', text="Email")
                if (x == "qualification"):
                    self.my_tree.heading("qualification", anchor='w', text="Qualification")
                if (x == "contact"):
                    self.my_tree.heading("contact", anchor='w', text="Contact")
                ...
                count = 0
            for record in cursor_variable:
                img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(record[5]))
                img.thumbnail((50, 50))  # resize the image to desired size
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
                self.my_tree.insert(parent='', index='end', iid=count, image = img, text='Parent',values= (record[0],record[1],record[2],record[3],record[4]))
                #self.my_tree.insert(parent="",index='end',iid=count,text='Parent',values=record)
                count += 1

            staff.close()
```

Comment: I have tested your code using my sample database and add back missing parts that make your code runs, it works fine. See my [result image](https://imgur.com/a/6U95X9I).

Comment: @acw1668 what have I done wrong in my code?

Comment: As I said, your code (especially the for loop to insert records into treeview) works fine.  Did you try to print out the record content to see whether records are actually retrieved from database?

Comment: @acw1668 when I used `print(record)` it shows (121, 'Archa', 'mailarcha@gmail.com', 'MTech', 7321568497). The image is not showing but the database has value for the attribute image. It also shows an error `IndexError: tuple index out of range` for accessing record[5]..

Comment: That means `record` has only five items, but you use `record[5]` (the sixth item) for the image.  `record` should have six items for your case. What is the SQL statement?

Comment: I modified the sql query as ` SELECT staff_id,name,email,qualification,contact,image FROM staff_details ` but now the output is as shown in the first image.. what should I check next?

Comment: It is because you did not save the references of the images, so it is garbage collected.  Try using a list (instance variable) to store the references of the images.

Comment: @acw1668 it was a useful tip.. but now my output shows an extra column corresponding to the image attribute. How will I avoid the last column created?

Comment: What do you mean *"extra column corresponding to the image attribute"*?

Comment: @acw1668 I created columns for treeview based on the values in the list attibutes_selected[ ]. I just removed the value 'image' from the attributes_selected[ ] and now it works fine.